# When is using weight regularization bad?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, weights, l2-regularization, l1-regularization

Regularization of weights (e.g. L1 or L2) keeps them small and standardized, which can help reduce data overfitting. From [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/weight-regularization-to-reduce-overfitting-of-deep-learning-models/), regularization sounds favorable in many cases, but is it always encouraged? Are there scenarios in which it should be avoided?